# use method() from other apex classes into the VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, dynamic-visualforce

Can we use method() from other apex classes into the VF page directly and by not using the controller of that VF page?

In Java, we can use package and do so, but I have no idea what to do with the apex and Vf page.

I would be thankful if anyone with the knowledge can help me out with this doubt.

Comment: why do you need to do this? There might be other alternatives but you'll need to provide some more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only alternative I know of is using a controller extension. Either build your method() in the controller extension, or refer it from the controller extension if it's already present in some other apex class.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm

Comment: Hi Guy,

Thanks for your reply.

I am aware of this process. I was just checking if we could do it without using the controller extension/ VF page controllers.